# How to force all messages to MMS?

Tags: samsung, sms, mms

I cannot send SMS on my Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra.  I can receive SMS and I can send/receive MMS.

I've spent hours on the phone with tech support from my carrier and Samsung.  I've sent the phone in for warranty repairs as well but still cannot send an SMS.  I've tried several 3rd-party messaging apps and they all have the same issue.

Is there any way to force a messaging app to send all texts through MMS? Any help is appreciated as I don't want to send the phone in again.

Answer (score 0):

Many messaging apps have an option to send long SMS messages as MMS or as a bunch of short SMS messages in a series.  A *"long"* SMS message is defined as more than 160 7-bit characters, 140 8-bit characters, or 70 16-bit characters.

It's not ideal, but in any of these apps (and there are scores of them), all you have to do is enable the "send as MMS" option and then ensure each message exceeds that limit.  You can pad the end of shorter messages with happy faces (our world always needs more happy faces! ), or perhaps just boring blank spaces if they don't get truncated by the app/carrier.